# How to change the style of a single view within a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles, floating-action-button

**Goal:** I am attempting to apply two different themes in one Fragment. One for the fragment's overall xml and the other for a particular view within that fragment's xml.

**Reason/Problem:** The reason for this is that it doesn't seem possible to change the entire background of a Floating Action Button to a vector using MaterialComponents, but it does work with appCompat.

Initially, I tried to change the theme in the xml using style="..." as shown below, but it appears to be reverting back to the theme declared in the manifest which is AppTheme1. I know this because I tested it by switching the theme declared there. That is, when I switched it to AppTheme2, the vector loaded properly in the FAB, but it crashed elsewhere since I have MaterialComponents throughout the app.

**Solution:** I think the obvious solution for this would be to change the theme for just the Floating Action Button in question, but I don't know how to do that. Any help much appreciated. Thank you!

```
         <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/nationality"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/flag_united_states_of_america"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                style="@style/AppTheme2"
                app:maxImageSize="56dp" />
```

**Themes:**

```
<style name="AppTheme1"  parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar" >
```

&&

```
<style name="AppTheme2"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
```

With MaterialComponents:

[image: MaterialComponentsVersion]

With AppCompat:

[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fabtest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So when the theme is changed from AppCompat to Material Components, the image resource no longer applied properly to the Floating Action Button. So I just want to apply AppCompat for Floating Action Button but keep the Material Components as the main style.

Comment: The style of a fab is not a theme. Really it is not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Alright, I will reword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can use:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    app:tint="@null"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/flag_united_states_of_america"
    ..>
```

The `FloatingActionButton` in the Material Components uses the `colorOnSecondary` attribute defined in your app theme to tint its icon (and the default value is `#000000`). If you don't want to tint the icon you have to use **`app:tint="@null"`**.

In general if you want to use a **custom style** in your FAB you can use:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      style="@style/MyCustomFab"
      ..>
```

with:

```
   <style name="MyCustomFab" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton>
      .....
      <item name="backgroundTint">@color/....</item>
      <item name="tint">@color/....</item>
   </style>
```

If you want to **override** the attribute defined in your app theme you can use:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:theme="@style/fab_themeoverlay"
      ..>
```

with:

```
   <style name="fab_themeoverlay" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton>
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
   </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the theme of the button, which has implications for how it is inflated, you should use `android:theme` instead of `android:style`.

Answer (score 0):

Both Ben P. and Gabrielle were semi-correct. The answer required both a change in the theme via:

```
android:theme="@style/SecondTheme"
```

and setting the tint to null:

```
app:tint="@null"
```

Both were required in this case

All together, given two themes, this is the correct XML for a FloatingActionButton if you want to change it's entire background to a vector while your primary theme is MaterialComponents as referenced in your app's manifest:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="10dp"
          app:borderWidth="0dp"

          app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_vector"
          app:tint="@null"
          android:theme="@style/SecondTheme"
          app:maxImageSize="56dp" />
```

Thank you Gabrielle and Ben for your help!